# Is the image of $\mathrm{Spec}(\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is a localization, always open?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S \subseteq R$ multiplicatively closed subset. Consider $\varphi: R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$ the localization of $R$ by $S$. Then it can be shown that the corresponding map

$\mathrm{Spec}(\varphi): \mathrm{Spec}S^{-1}R \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}R  \;$ defined by $\;\mathfrak{a}\mapsto \varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})$

is a homeomorphism (with respect to the Zariski topologies) between $\mathrm{Spec}S^{-1}R$ and its image $U:=\{\mathfrak{q} \in \mathrm{Spec}R \;|\; \mathfrak{q} \cap S= \emptyset\}$.

If we assume the set $S$ to be "principal", i.e. of the form $\{f^n \; | \;n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for some $f \in R$, then it is easy to see that the image $U$ is actually of the form $\mathrm{Spec}R \setminus V((f))$, therefore open.

My question is:

**What happens in the case of a general multiplicative set? Namely, is the set $U$ always open? If not, is the above result (i.e. the mentioned homeomorphism) still interesting for some reason(s)?**

I am also interested in examples, where the set $U$ is not open (if it is possible) and conditions on the ring $R$ which would force the set $U$ to be open (for any choice of $S$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U$ can be any intersection of basic-open subsets. If it was always open, this would mean that open subsets are closed under arbitrary intersections. Of course this fails in the common examples. You should be able to find an example for $R=\mathbb{Z}$. [Always look at examples, algebraic geometry is not as abstract as it looks like at first sight  ...]

The result you mention is useful because it shows for example that the scheme-theoretic fiber of a morphism of schemes has as underlying topological space the usual fiber.

Comment: I see, if I take $S$ to be for example generated by all primes $p \equiv 1\; (\text{mod }4)$, then $U$ cannot be open. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, or just take $S=R \setminus \{0\}$ (i.e. which is generated by *all* primes) and remark that the generic point is not open.